# Precision problem with mathematica

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, evaluation, precision-and-accuracy

I have a precision problem with a complicated function in Mathematica. I need to get norm (`NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]`) and shape (`f[x]/norm`) of this function for several values of parameters. When pushing parameters to extremely large or small values, the computation quickly loses precision and breaks. I try to report here the full code to reproduce the problem, unfortunately, the definition of the function is very long

```
subst = {\[Mu] -> 1.0649627263045793` m\[Chi], 
   m\[Chi] -> m0, \[Mu]F -> 0.126881598`, \[Sigma]0 -> 
    5.137783801543852`*^-18, nn -> 0.0022767242753033053`, 
   B0 -> 0.5801875039070804`, mn -> 0.939`};
```

The function is defined at this paste (does not fit in here) https://pastebin.com/raw/4b2wHFUA

Here are some example plots that show the problem

```
(*For values of T and M0 that are not too small/large, the function \
evaluates with good precision*)
T = 1/10^5;
Plot[DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^3 /. n -> 0, {x, 0, 1}]

(*For values of T and M0 that are not too small/large, the function \
evaluates with good precision*)
T = 1/10^5;
Plot[DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^5 /. n -> 0, {x, 0, 1}]

(*Pushing m0 and T to very small/large values causes problems, like \
here (the shape should be the same as before, but is not precise...)*)
T = 1/10^7;
Plot[DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^7 /. n -> 0, {x, 0, 1}]

(*Another issue that can happen are fuzzy plots like this*)
T = 1/10^5;
Plot[DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^7 /. n -> 0, {x, 0, 1}]

(*Going even more down/up in values, it breaks completely*)
T = 1/10^9;
Plot[DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^7 /. n -> 0, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I would need to make it work for m0 up to 10^9 and T down to 1/10^10. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using exact math works:

```
subst = SetPrecision[{μ -> 1.0649627263045793` mχ,
                      mχ -> m0,
                      μF -> 0.126881598`,
                      σ0 -> 5.137783801543852`*^-18,
                      nn -> 0.0022767242753033053`,
                      B0 -> 0.5801875039070804`,
                      mn -> 0.939`},
                     ∞];

T = 1/10^9;
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, DGamma[x*T, T] /. subst /. m0 -> 10^7 /. n -> 0}, {x, 0, 1, 1/100}]]
```

[image]